# Key bindings vs. setMnemonic, setDisplayedMnemonic, and setLabelFor

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I feel like a kid in a candy store--in trying yet again to get a handle on key bindings I stumbled onto `setMnemonic()` (in Netbeans form designer and its ton of generated code) and [especially!] the `setDisplayedMnemonic()` / `setActionFor()` pair (from Googling "can jlabel have mnemonic"), which seems a godsend.

All I know is that the following code just made my latest app a whole lot more user friendly in that it has rendered mouse/touchpad unnecessary.

```
btnRemoveScratchWords.setMnemonic(VK_C);
btnSearch.setMnemonic(VK_H);
btnClearOutput.setMnemonic(VK_O);
btnExit.setMnemonic(VK_X);
btnHelp.setMnemonic(VK_H);

lblPattern.setDisplayedMnemonic(VK_P);
lblPattern.setLabelFor(txtPattern);

lblLegal.setDisplayedMnemonic(VK_L);
lblLegal.setLabelFor(txtLegal);

lblMust.setDisplayedMnemonic(VK_R);
lblMust.setLabelFor(txtRequiredLetters);

lblMinimumPointsPerLetter.setDisplayedMnemonic(VK_R);
lblMinimumPointsPerLetter.setLabelFor(txtMinScore);
```

But is key bindings a better way to do this?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: This site is about asking questions, and getting answers. Don't use it as a blog. Ask a concrete, as short as possible, easy to understand question. Don't post all your random thoughts. Don't make blog posts.

Comment: I guess ONE reason key bindings are better is that there are THREE possible mappings--one when the component itself has focus, one when it contains the component that has the focus, and one when its window has the focus, according to a document I just read. And I guess if the action needs to be changed, since it's external to the pair of mapping statements, that's convenient.

Comment: @JB, you missed my point--"give me feedback on my approach," which is a sort of question in that it hopes to elicit a response--but that's my fault. Here's the question: **Is it better to use key binding key-action pairs of statements (`getInputMap`/`getActionMap`) than what I did?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna answer my own question. If I've made any errors or misinterpreted or misinformed, I hope to find out from someone. Question in advance: Did I mess anything up below?

Key bindings provide the only way to do some things. For instance...

I needed a **keypress to cause the bottom line of a textarea to be displayed regardless of which component has the focus and to then select the contents of the 'main' textbox.**

The statements below link the physical F2 keypress to a logical button on the form, whose 
action will be defined in a class (named `JumpToEndOfOutput`) that extends `AbstractAction`, as required by `getActionMap`.

```
   txaOutput.getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(getKeyStroke("F2"),
                                "jumpToEndOfOutput");
   txaOutput.getActionMap().put("jumpToEndOfOutput", jumpToEndOfOutput);
```

(note use of `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`, without which F2 can't always do what's needed):

```
// in constructor for form... make action listener for button

   btnJumpToEndOfOutput.addActionListener( new ButtonListener() );
```

...

```
// inner class avoids anonymous inner class, for clarity

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener // simulates click of logical form button
    {
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent bp )
        {    
          txaOutput.selectAll();
          txtPattern.grabFocus();
          txtPattern.select(0, 99);
        } 
    }
```

...

```
// back to constructor... make action object to listen for F2 keystroke

      JumpToEndOfOutput jumpToEndOfOutput = new JumpToEndOfOutput();
```

...

```
// class required for getActionMap

   class JumpToEndOfOutput extends AbstractAction // catches physical F2 keystroke
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
           btnJumpToEndOfOutput.doClick(); 
        } 
    }
```

Is there a shorter way to accomplish this?

Comment: OK... downvote but don't identify your reason, which is pretty much par for the course at SO. BTW, I based my solution on code found at [this link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/245148-java-key-binding-tutorial-and-demo-program/), which is the only reason it worked. I knew nothing about key bindings 4 days ago except that most find them very hard to grasp at first, if not longer. I'm not sure the URL above is the best place to turn for initial success, but it worked for me.

Comment: I just unedited my edits of my original post and added a question at the end, FWIW.